# setTimeout function in chrome extension popup.js issues

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, settimeout

I have a popup.js file that includes a series of functions. I'm trying to run a function which is set to run when a new tab is created, but with a short delay. Here is a function example and the solutions I've tried.

```
// function.
function foo_bar()
{
 // some ajax call.
}

// try 1
setTimeout(foo_bar,1000);
EDIT:// executed without delay.

// try 2
setTimeout(function(){
//some ajax call.
},1000)
EDIT:// executed without delay.

// try 3
setTimeout(function(){
foo_bar();
},1000)
EDIT: // didn't seem to execute.

// try 4 and 5
window.addEventListener('load',foo_bar());
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',foo_bar());
// no delay takes place. The function completes before the page even loads.


// try 6
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {...}); 
// used the status from here to wait till page load is complete.
//problem with this is that sometimes the status doesn't get updated.

// try 7
// tried to delay the php script by using sleep(2), but ajax call would never complete.
```

Can anyone please help? Not sure if it helps, but the script is not defined as background or content.

EDIT: some more detail. The function called is executing an ajax call to a remote server, then based on the data, manipulating the page the new tab landed on, using chrome.tabs.executeScript. Only problem is, the page isn't ready half the time.

Comment: What was wrong with tries 1-3?

Comment: Sorry, just updated it. To delay the function, I added the delay amount in miliseconds. The first two worked without the delay. Try three never called the function.

Answer (score 1):

Tries 4 and 5 should be:

```
window.addEventListener('load',foo_bar);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',foo_bar);
```

No delay took place because you called them inline.

Comment: I tried this out. The function doesn't run if I call it like this. It seems to work only if () is included.

Comment: @Jack that's because you're calling it right then, which isn't what you want. Is this a Content Script: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html ?

Comment: no, it's not defined as a content script. It's just a .js file generating the popup.

Comment: @jack, jack, any update on this? I am using setTimeout() in my google-chrome extension (script.js). But it doesn't seem to trigger at all. Did you get it fixed?

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't work as expected, it executes immediately, no matter what delay you specify!